# Is it necessary or advisable to remove the spark-plugs prior to rotating the crankshaft by hand?

Tags: renault, crankshaft, crank, sandero

K7m Engine(renault sandero)

I tried rotating the crankshaft by hand(for alignment purposes during a timing-belt change) and it does move but it's a bit on the stiff side and I'm worried about the main crank pulley bolt moving independently of the crank shaft.

I was hoping not to have to buy another spark-plug socket because this may turn out to be a one off and my one is too large to fit down the chimney so-to-speak.

If I'm not risking any misalignment due to the stiffness(I'm guessing that has to do with air compression as the cylinder and pistons move up and down), then I'll just leave the spark-plugs for now. This is not about servicing the vehicle.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparkplugs in? Sparkplugs out? Makes absolutely no difference other than how stiff it becomes when you come up on compression in any given cylinder with them in. The only thing I do differently with sparkplugs in is to just give it a little bit of time as it comes up on compression to allow the pressure to bleed off. Other than that ... no worries.

Comment: I have a new timing-belt and tensioner in, now. 

I noticed during the 2x revolution rotation of the crank that the tension-tooth changes position i.e. it moves off the gap.

Is that because of the change in compression, as it goes through the phases?

Comment: Are you talking about alignment marks on the belt as they line up on the gears? Or are you talking about the alignment marks as they should be against the markers on the block? If the alignment marks on the belt, they move because of how the number of teeth work out. If on the gears to block marks, if they don't line up after the two revs, you've done something wrong and need to start over.

Comment: If there is a natural (accounted for) variation in tension with variation in compression, then I'm not too worried.

Comment: It;s just that I've been rotating the crank-shaft and I have had to preceed or exceed the TDC markings to get the locking-pin in far enough.

So TDC is out, but I have original markings on gears and casings (both crank and cam). Max variation is one tooth, and even then it may be the safe side of one tooth, if you know what I mean..

I'm just wondering if it is something to be alarmed about when I see tensioner-tooth is off, pre-TDC.

Comment: If I push hard on the belt I can see slight movement on the tensioner-tooth. So I thought perhaps the spark-plug-in compression may have something to do with that.

Comment: p.s. I have been ignoring the markings on the actual new belt. I figured these are going to move and are only useful in the first couple of revolutions.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jim - I'd ask if you have a new question to ask it and not try to get answers to your issues through comments. That's not really how Stack Exchange works.